# How to remove block from left or right panel in magento 2?

Tags: magento2, layout, blocks

I want to remove compare product and wish list block from left panel.

I don't want to change template. I am using `2columns-left`.

in magento 1.x, We uses like following in layout file.

```
<cms_index_index>
   <reference name="left">
      <remove name="left.newsletter"/>
   </reference>
</cms_index_index>
```

What to do to remove block from magento 2.x?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Its almost the very same way

```
<referenceBlock name="block.name.wantoberemoved" remove="true"/>
```

Remove compare products from sidebar

```
<referenceBlock name="catalog.compare.sidebar" remove="true" />
```

Remove Wishlist from sidebar

```
<referenceBlock name="wishlist_sidebar" remove="true" />
```

Answer (score 5):

In Magento 2, you can remove Compare products and Wishlist from sidebar blocks of Category Page through xml. 
You can remove it by adding a default.xml file to your theme in: *theme_dir/Magento_Catalog/layout/default.xml*

**And add below XML**

> ```
> <page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
>  <body>
>     <referenceBlock name="catalog.compare.sidebar" remove="true"/>
>     <referenceBlock name="sidebar.additional" remove="true"/>
>  </body>
> </page>
> ```

Answer (score 3):

The code works fine in Magento 2.1.1.

With little changes :

instead `referenceBlock` replace with `referenceContainer`

```
<referenceContainer name="block.name.wantoberemoved" remove="true"/>
```

Answer (score 3):

You can create new deafult.xml in your custom module and write below code to remove recent order block from Left sidebar

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../../../../htdocs/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
     <referenceContainer name="sidebar.additional">
         <referenceBlock name="catalog.compare.sidebar" remove="true"/>
         <referenceBlock name="wishlist_sidebar" remove="true"/>
     </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

Answer (score 3):

What worked for me, even via admin "Layout XML Update" field, was the code

```
<referenceContainer name="sidebar.additional" remove="true" />
```

Answer (score 3):

A quick note for Enterprise users: you may need to remove the "multiple wishlist" block as well:

```
<referenceBlock name="multiple-wishlist_sidebar" remove="true" />
```

Comment: Man, I could not get wishlist sidebar to go away on an EE site. This worked perfect. Thank you!